# npm install -g @vue/cli VUE CLI INSTALL ERROR

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm-install, vue-cli

I just wanted to install Vue CLI and I got this errors. I have the latest version of node.js as you can see below. I tried some different ways like `npm uninstall -g vue-cli` and `npm cache clean --force`. But they have not worked. How can I fix that?

My npm version is 7.0.3.

```
C:\Users\HALİL_MONSTER>NODE
Welcome to Node.js v15.0.1.
Type ".help" for more information.

C:\Users\HALİL_MONSTER>npm install -g @vue/cli
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path C:\Users\HALİL_MONSTER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli
npm ERR! dest C:\Users\HALİL_MONSTER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\.cli-P415H8gb
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\HALİL_MONSTER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli' -> 'C:\Users\HALİL_MONSTER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\.cli-P415H8gb'
npm ERR!  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\HALİL_MONSTER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli' -> 'C:\Users\HALİL_MONSTER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\.cli-P415H8gb'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'rename',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\HALİL_MONSTER\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@vue\\cli',
npm ERR!   dest: 'C:\\Users\\HALİL_MONSTER\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@vue\\.cli-P415H8gb'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\HALİL_MONSTER\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2020-10-30T19_06_23_457Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Try `npm install -g @vue/cli --unsafe-perm`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using windows 7 and nodejs 13. I meet the same issue. I have tried restart my pc, add flags etc. nothing works.
Finally I solve it using yarn.

1. Install the yarn using npm:  npm install --global yarn
2. Install the vue cli using yarn: yarn global add @vue/cli
3. Configure the system path that vue cli installed. yarn doesnt install vue cli in the directory as npm

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with downloading Vue in the terminal.
I solved this issue by using:

```sh
sudo npm install -g @vue/cli
```

I then check that it installed correctly and was up to date with:

```
vue --version
```

Comment: I tried but it did not work at first. Then I reinstall windows and tried again it worked.